# Remove a dynamically added form group which includes a label and textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically generated form using php. The form includes select boxes that can contain an other option. When a user clicks the other option, a required other input box is created below the select. I have been able to create the other box but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the added section if the user decides to change their selection from other to another selection.

```
    <form id="form">    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Choose one of the following"><b>Choose one of the following</b><span class="asterisk"> *</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="62" id="62" required="required" onchange="showOther(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="">Choose One</option>
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <small id="sm_Choose one of the following" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    </form>


    <script>
    function showOther(name) {

        var varName = name + "_1";
        var varField = "#" + varName;

        if (name == 'Other') {

           if (!$(varField).length) {

           $('<div class="form-group"><label for="Other"><b>Other</b><span class="asterisk"> *</span></label><input type="text" name="' + varName + '" id="' + varName + '"></div>').appendTo('#form');
           }

         } else {

            if ($(varField).length == 0) {
            //remove other box if found

         }
       }
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add id="remove" to your div and then replace HTML with nothing.

```
document.getElementById("remove").outerHTML = "";
```

If you have jQuery you can use

```
$( "#remove" ).remove();
```

Error will show of course if there is nothing to remove.

**EDIT:**
Now code checks if element exists.

```js
function showOther(name) {

        var varName = name + "_1";
        var varField = "#" + varName;

        if (name == 'Other') {

           if (!$(varField).length) {

           $('<div class="form-group" id="remove"><label for="Other"><b>Other</b><span class="asterisk"> *</span></label><input type="text" name="' + varName + '" id="' + varName + '"></div>').appendTo('#form');
           }

         } else {

            if ($(varField).length == 0) {
            //remove other box if found
            var element =  document.getElementById('remove');
if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
{
  document.getElementById("remove").outerHTML = "";
}
            

         }
       }
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Choose one of the following"><b>Choose one of the following</b><span class="asterisk"> *</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="62" id="62" required="required" onchange="showOther(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="">Choose One</option>
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <small id="sm_Choose one of the following" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I added a unique id for that div when created and used it to remove. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NickKester Np, i have edited my code now code checks if element with id remove exists, and no error is made like this. You just use your id's.